# Why upgrade an application to latest version of Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm just trying to understand the factors that are considered to decide that an application written in a lower version needs to be upgraded.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to think it comes down to these factors:

1. The Rails team is pretty active and they remedy Rails core security issues as soon as they come across one. It would be nice to have your Rails version always updated which means your have all the security issues of the past addressed as well as open to further updates if they come along. You would not want an older version of Rails get in the way of a security update.
2. There are always performance improvements in almost every new version of Rails and optimization is an area to work in for Rails apps. You should take advantage of them by keeping your Rails version updated.
3. Its not only the Rails version, the underlying Ruby version also receives updates and performance improvements. The updated version of Rails makes use of these.
4. There is also the gem dependency issue. Gems also receive updates and security patches and at times, newer versions of these gems are not compatible with an older version of Rails.
5. It is easier to upgrade a Rails application to its next version than to its next|next|next|next version. Blog posts and migration guides are always online but if you are coming from a very very old Rails version, they will become very hard to follow.
6. Newer versions of Rails provide functionality that is not available in the older versions of Rails. It is always nice to have this functionality at your disposal. You never know you may need it in your project.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer. In addition, a rails app not kept up-to-date w.r.t. ruby/rails versions becomes difficult to maintain over time. One application I worked on was struck on ruby 1.8.7/rails 2.3.8 for years, and multiple different teams worked on for nearly a year to get it up to a more recent version of ruby/rails before being able to add functionality to the system.